# Wake up a GoPro from sleep mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, gopro

for a project I need to control a GoPro from a mobile application made with Ionic.

I have done the start / stop recording part. But the problem is that the Gopro always goes on a "sleep mode", and I need to press a button to wake up the GoPro.

I saw that I could wake up it with a magic packet. The problem is that I never did a magic packet (here: https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/master/HERO4/WifiCommands.md#power), I don't know where and how to start.

Ionic is using Typescript as programming language.
So if someone could help me doing a magic packet with Typescript I would be so grateful! Thanks!

(By the way, the I tried to disable the "auto off" and more but it didn't work).

Comment: This sounds similar to, if not the same as, standard WoL (Wake on Lan) packet.s It's unlikely that you'll be able to send these packets over the network without a plugin as it'll be at a lower level than is normally available to JavaScript.

Comment: @phuzi, In my opinion, it is the same as standard WoL (but I can be wrong). I already did some researches for a Ionic plugin that helps to make WoL requests, but all I found is a plugin made 7 years ago, and obviously not working in my case

Comment: Considering sockets are usually handled at lower level, I doubt a WoL command is available on Typescript.